# What is the difference between the way the brain sends signals as opposed to how an electronic device sends signals?

Tags: electric-circuits, biophysics, biology, electrochemistry

As I understand it, a brain communicates through sending signals via ions and chemical reactions resulting in concentrations of ions, a computer sends signals by electrons. I'm really trying to do 3 things:

1. Confirm that understanding
2. Understand what is the fundamental difference between the two types of signaling.
3. Is there more to what the brain is doing at least at a relatively macro level that I may be missing.

Please help me refine my question if needed.

Comment: Have you tried doing some internet research? eg googling your title? The #1 hit is [Neuroscience for Kids : Brain v Computer](https://faculty.washington.edu/chudler/bvc.html)

Comment: Yes, I have.  I'm really trying to confirm what I am reading and get a little bit deeper understanding of what happens.  I actually got a very good response over on Cognitive Sciences https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/18662/difference-between-brain-and-electronic-device-signals

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable for [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/18662/difference-between-brain-and-electronic-device-signals) and already has an answer there.

Comment: Perhaps more important in the distinction is how the signal codes information (bits vs spikes(?)) and how a computation is performed (that is, how information is processed). The difference is more important than the physical nature of the signal.

Comment: Bruce, what I'm wondering is,  ultimately what exists is the signal,  right?  You aren't just doing computation, your neurons fire in a specific sequence that results in what we experience.  They may be computing what to fire to produce that experience but when they all do signal its the culmination of multiple signals.  So ultimately I'm trying to understand why the physical nature of the signal isn't important.  I get that it's a cognitive science question, but I think it is still a physics question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Here are some differences between the two types of signaling:
the propagation speed of the ionic charge difference that flows along a nerve pathway is on the order of ~tens of meters a second because it is driven by things like chemical concentration gradients whereas the propagation speed of an electrical signal along a piece of wire is on the order of ~300,000,000 meters a second because it is driven by the interactions between conduction electrons which occur at the speed of light. also, the nerve pathway has to be "reset" between impulses by re-establishing the resting state of all the ions and charges along the length of the nerve cell whereas the wire is ready for the next signal essentially instantly after passing its signal.

In the brain, the situation becomes far more complex because there are different families of nerve cells which use different chemical reactions to transmit impulses between cells, and the sensitivity of those transmissions is modulated by the concentration of special chemicals called neurotransmitters which reside in the junctions between those cells.

I've barely scratched the surface here; physicists spend entire careers elucidating the details of electrical wave propagation in the solid state, and  neuroscientists who deal with neurotransmission and brain chemistry do the same.

Comment: Be careful with capitalisation, punctuation, etc.

Comment: mea culpa, magister.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you did get the differences in signaling, but, answering (3): there's a lot missing in this picture.

It's unlikely that an essential role is played by the details of physical nature of the signals traveling inside the machine/brain $-$ in computers these signals have been mechanical before being electrical, and one day they [might be light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_computing). Probably what really matters is the [hundreds of different neuron types](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/brainwaves/know-your-neurons-classifying-the-many-types-of-cells-in-the-neuron-forest/), the way they connect, and the often overlooked dynamics of it all.

Also, it might very well be that the whole computer paradigm for explaining the brain is deeply flawed, as defended, for instance, in [The empty brain: Your brain does not process information, retrieve knowledge or store memories. In short: your brain is not a computer](https://aeon.co/essays/your-brain-does-not-process-information-and-it-is-not-a-computer).

Comment: my answer contained the qualification that it was not complete, and  I made no reference to the brain-as-computer paradigm. I did mention neuron types and the brain chemistry associated with them at a level of detail I thought appropriate given the manner in which the OP phrased the questions. And in dealing with my own brain for the last 65 years,  I have found it an excellent tool to process information, retrieve knowledge and store memories, and I do not think in the present context it matters whether I choose to call it a "computer" or not.

Comment: @nielsnielsen, you sound offended because I answered the question too. What's going on?

Comment: I'm sorry stafusa; I assumed that you were the source of the downvote. I admit to being sensitive about that here because I am not a professional physicist and cannot furnish answers on the level of those who obviously are, and I have been downvoted in the past for answers considered incomplete.

Comment: Ok, @nielsnielsen, the *first* downvote wasn't mine $-$ after (supposedly) you downvoted mine, I did take that to mean "ok, we're being stringent here" and could find your answer missing and vote it down. I regretted that and retracted that arguably childish vote. I went looking at some of your other answers, and found them to be pretty good actually (no downvote anywhere, even *before* your last comment). Thanks for contributing, keep it up. And sorry for the misunderstanding. All the best.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer- what i did was upvote the OP's question by clicking the upvote arrow on the OP's question. the earlier downvote that stung the worst was one where I deleted my answer afterward to wipe the slate clean, so you probably can't see it... even though I felt my answer was correct.   Anyway, thank you for your thoughtful reply, I appreciate it. best regards, niels